# Security for login by session in php

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables

I'm using session variable for login purpose. If login is successful `$_SESSION['userName']` is set. In some pages there are codes like `if(isset($_SESSION['userName'])) echo $_SESSION['userName];`
I wonder if `$_SESSION['userName']` is already set by other website in someone's browser it will lead to a huge problem. How may I overcome this problem, please suggest.

Comment: Before asking how you can solve a problem, did you ask yourself how you can reproduce it? You might realize this problem does not exist after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session value is communicated between a browser and a server by HTTP cookie.
The HTTP cookie is only shared on the same host name like (*.stackoverflow.com)
So, I think another website cannot be get a session value of others.

Comment: I was not aware of these things. Thank you, I have got my solution from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how a PHP session works.

PHP generates a session id for a specific user. It then hashes that ID and passes the hash to the user as a cookie.

On each subsequent request the user send that cookie back, PHP and looks up the session data for that session hash. It is then able to start the session associated with that user. In that sense no other user is able to access the first user's session without knowing the session hash.

However the end user is vulnerable to session hijacking in case someone else steals their cookies and there's a number of ways this can happen.

1. Session fixation which someone tricks a user of your site to use a session ID that someone has provided them (there's not much you can do about this).
2. Man in the middle attacks where someone is between the user and your website and intercepts all data that get passed along. This usually can be protected against by serving the page under HTTPS (not always but it's a lot harder for someone to steal data that comes over HTTPS).
3. Cross-site scripting (XSS), when someone uses client-side code (which can access cookies) to impersonate that user. You can protect against this by implementing CORS restrictions and sending a ["nonce"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) with each response which you expect the user to return when they send the next request.
4. Taking advantage of browser exploits that expose the user's cookies to another website. It's normally a requirement to browser manufacturers to prevent websites from accessing cookies they did not set, but sometimes bugs can be present that prevent this. This is usually taken care of if the user keeps their browser up to date (not because exploits are not there but because most people haven't found them yet).
5. Someone breaks into a user's house and uses the user's browser (can't do anything about this one either).

There's probably more ways